# How to download and declare a large number of images from Firebase Storage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am creating an iOS app (in Xcode with Swift) that displays a large number of trading cards to the user. The card information (name, attack, etc) is stored in the Firebase Database in the form of a JSON file. I would like to store the images for each card in Firebase Storage, but don't know how to retrieve them in a way that would be similar to having a populated Assets.xcassets folder.

If possible I would like to loop through all images in storage and declare each one as a UIImage so that they can later be called by name by my collectionView and be displayed.

Is there a way to declare hundred of variables with a loop, each with a unique variable name? How would I set these variables to the images I saved in storage?

Most of the code I have seen for downloading from storage has looked similar to this:

```
// Create a reference to the file you want to download
let islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg")

// Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)

islandRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
    // ... let islandImage: UIImage! = UIImage(data: data!)
  }
}
```

This only downloads one image, naming the variable "islandImage." I need to be able to do this for every item in my firebase database.

Comment: Typically you would store the URL's in the database, retrieve them and use those to them retrieve the images from storage. So for example, you had a node in the database /urls and then a 'list' of each URL. /url0: "image 0" and /url1: "image 1" etc. You would then observe the /urls node and populate an array with those urls. Then iterate over the array to retrieve the images from the database. Does that work?

Comment: @Jay when you say "retrieve"'the images in the observe method, what do you mean exactly? For example would each image be stored in an array instead of in variables? (I've been warned against storing images in an array, as it causes memory issues)

Comment: It depends on your use case. Images can be tiny thumbnails which can be kept in an array with no issues. If they are huge multi-gig files, that's obviously not the best solution. 'Retrieve' could mean a number of things but with Firebase there are two options: download to memory or download to disk, both covered [Firebase Datastore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files). Array's are 'structures of variables' often times holding classes. Imagine a class: Playing_Card; the image on the card (spades, heart etc) are .jpg and the value of the card is an int 2-14 (Ace)

Comment: and... there is no problem storing 'images' in an array. After all, images are just a series of bytes (bits) like a string. It all comes down to how big they are and the use case. However, if your images are static, they should be included as part of the app instead of downloading them.

Comment: @Jay before I tried using storage etc, I was using an array of card objects that had a UIImage in it, and this would cause the memory to fill up and crash because I have hundreds of images. I need a way to save these images without putting them in an array

Comment: Hundreds of images would not generally be an issue - look at any popular game - they certainly don't download ALL of the graphics when you want to play the game - they are stored locally. However, and I stress, it depends on how large the images are and how you manipulate them in code. 1000 x 5k images is a tiny amount of space and would not cause any issues. I'm not saying it's the best solution but it's not a large amount of data. I would suspect if you're crashing, there's other issues causing it (or maybe the image sizes or use)

Comment: @Jay hmm but storing them in an array would prevent them from being freed at a memory warning. Since arrays are what I did last time and it didn't work, I'm not sure if id want to swap this to arrays again. Would NSCache work? I've never used it

Comment: Your question states 'download a large number' so whether they are stored locally or retrieved from Firebase, they are still using memory - and pulling static graphics on the fly from Firebase in a game setting may not be the best solution as far as a responsive experience for the user goes. I would suggest identifying how much memory each image takes up multiply that out by the number of images to come up with a total amount. It's possible the images can be compressed to a small size or filetype and (best solution) embed into the app itself.

Comment: Watch Zero to App: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE and check out the sample code: https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd

Answer (score 0):

if you're fetching large amount of data from firebase, maybe you should consider using pagination to fetch a few images at a time to avoid frozen UI. Below i have a sample function from Brian Voong's Instagram firebase course(https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course/Instagram-Firebase).

```
    fileprivate func paginatePosts() {

    guard let uid = self.user?.uid else {return}
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid)

    var query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate")


    if posts.count > 0 {
        let value = posts.last?.creationDate.timeIntervalSince1970
        query = query.queryEnding(atValue: value)

    }

    query.queryLimited(toLast: 4).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("all snapshots: ", snapshot)
        guard var allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

        allObjects.reverse()

        if allObjects.count < 4 {
            self.isFinishedPaging = true
        }

        if self.posts.count > 0 && allObjects.count > 0 {
            allObjects.removeFirst()
        }

        guard let user = self.user else {return}

        allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in

            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else {return}
            var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)

            post.id = snapshot.key

            self.posts.append(post)

        })

        self.posts.forEach({ (post) in

        })

        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to paginate for posts:", err)
    }

}
```